# Material slider not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, cross-browser

Material slider is not working in google chrome. Its working fine in firefox and IE.

HTML

```
<html>
<input class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" type="range" id="levelWithMaterial" min="1" max="10" value="1" />
</html>
```

On change event

```
$("#levelWithMaterial").on("change",function(){

alert("changed")

})
```

Here is the link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46fgae11/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your event to a input type event:

```
$("#levelWithMaterial").on("input change",function(){
$(".level-value-with").text($(this).val());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/46fgae11/1/

Comment: then use both events

Comment: After adding the input event it is firing the event multiple times. How can I prevent this? I want my event to be triggered with the last value of slider

Comment: @Jerry you can't do that, the events trigger when you change the slider

Comment: I expect the event to work the same way it works for change in other browsers. Like on mouse up I want to trigger the event.

Comment: you can tigger the event at mouse up and remove the change/input events

Comment: why did you retract the answer if the answer is correct for your current question ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "oninput" attribute on the slider element like this:

```js
window.materialSlide = function(value) {
  $(".level-value-with").text(value);
}
$("#levelWithoutMaterial").on("change",function() {
  $(".level-value-without").text($(this).val());
});
```

```css
.level-value-without,.level-value-with{font-weight:bold;color:blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.min.js"></script>

        <div class="menu-card-settings">
    <h5 class="">
     Level Depth with Material Class
    </h5>
    <p>
     <input oninput="materialSlide(this.value)" class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider cursor-pointer" type="range" id="levelWithMaterial" min="1" max="10" value="1" />
    </p>
    <span class="level-value-with">1</span>
        <h5 class="roboto-font-family text">
     Level Depth without Material Class
    </h5>
    <p>
     <input class=" cursor-pointer" type="range" id="levelWithoutMaterial" min="1" max="10" value="1" />
    </p>
    <span class="level-value-without">1</span>
</div>
```